# What are the Benefits of having a Guild?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Which benefits may apply for people for being members of guilds?

I Know that there is a "Guild Influence" system but I'm not sure how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Guild Rewards:**

Members earn influence for the guild that they represent by being present and participating in activities. The more members that participate together, the faster the guild gains influence, which can be used to purchase upgrades for the guild in four categories:

1. [Architecture](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Architecture#Architecture) : Purchase shared storage and increase the number of upgrades the guild can work on at once.
2. [Art of War](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Art_of_War#Art_of_War) : Buffs used in WvW
3. [Economy](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Economy#Economy):Buffs to increase members ability to earn karma, find magic items, or gather materials.
4. [Politics](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Politics#Politics) : Emblems, influence buffs, guild armor, and party items

**Represent!**

You are able to join multiple guilds in the game, without having to leave your current guild. This is done through representation; representing is required in order to see your guilds chat, perks and bank. When you represent a guild, all of your activities that grant Influence will be awarded to the represented guild.
When you start a new character, represent a guild because if you do not, you will not gain the benefits of representation (chat, bank, perks, etc.)

**World Vs World:**

Guilds participating in World versus World can claim objectives, display their banner over these locations, and benefit from bonuses purchased using influence.

**Influence System:**

Influence is the currency that guilds spend to purchase boons and other guild-wide upgrades. Influence is earned by participating in events, pvp, or solo content while representing a guild. Coin may also be exchanged for influence at the [Guild Promoter.](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Guild_Promoter)

However, Influence is accrued and spent separately by the guild members on each world. For example, a guild with players in Maguuma, Blacktide, and Riverside will have three different pools of Influence and three different build queues, one for each world.

**Influence Gain in Numbers:**

*Attendance*:
The game checks once every 24 hours for members who have logged on and represented the guild during the previous 24 hours.

[image]10  per member for the first 20 members.

[image]5  per each additional member.

*Participation:* These amounts increase depending on the number of guild members in the same party.

Events: [image]2 /person for solo.

PvP Victories : [image] 5/person

Dungeon Completion : [image] 10/Person for Individuals and
[image] for completion by a guild party

*Buying Influence:* You can buy influence with coin at a Guild Promoter at a rate of 20  per point in the following increments.

10 [image] for 2 Silver coins [image]

100 [image] for 20 Silver Coins [image]

1,000 [image] for 2 Gold Coins [image]

10,000 [image] for 20 Gold Coins [image]

**Influence Usage:**

Influence can be spent in the guild panel in four categories: Architecture, The Art of War, Economy, and Politics. If a guild member cancels an upgrade currently in the queue, the influence is refunded to the guild. However, if influence has been spent in order to reduce the build time of an upgrade, this influence is NOT refunded.

For More on influence, check : [Wiki Influence Page](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Influence)